# HTML5 / Javascript Parallax Effect on single elements / div tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, parallax

I have created a few sites in the past with the scrolldeck.js that have the standard full screen background with one layer ontop and text (the standard scroll parallax style) this is not what I am looking for.

Im looking for a script or tutorial (or examples) for having a single div tag (image) in the foreground animate/move as you scroll. I will be using this on a one page vertical scrolling site, so as your scrolling I would like the odd image to scroll in at a different speed and have a start and stop position. I dont want the entire background on parallax.

Thanks a bunch in advance

---

EDIT: Here is a better explanation of what Im looking for:

Picture scrolling down a page, as you scroll you see a bottle thats floating (transparent png), you continue to scroll down reading content and at a certain point that bottle rests nicely on a table (part of background) as you keep scrolling it will no longer move.

Pretty well the goal is to have elements (images) move into pre-determined positions (based on scrolling) and then stay put once they get to their final resting position.

---

EDIT 2: Here are some example sites:

http://jessandruss.us/ - this site does exactly what I want about 2/3 of the way down at this point: [see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw2nI.jpg)

http://smokeybones.com/ - the burger pretty well does the effect I want, minimal but it moves into position as you scroll.

Comment: Okay, so just to get a little more background on this - you have a side scrolling website (I've made my fair share of them).  The screaming obvious thing is the position:fixed property for your background image, and also the background-size:cover property - what is it exactly that you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Depending on what kind of animation you want, you can work out the percentage of the 'scroll' using the size (in px) of the document and the screen to animate something using the end percentage.

Comment: Do you have something like this is mind? http://jsfiddle.net/WQcWG/ You could probably edit it to give it a smoother animation.

Comment: Rikonator, thats very close to what I want, but I dont necessarily want it to start at the top or move directly down. I will also be using this on quite a few elements so was hoping for a simpler method.

I will have a standard VERTICAL scrolling site, as your scrolling throughout the pages I want the odd element (image) to start scrolling parallax style and fall into a predetermined position. Pretty well just like that jsfiddle posted. I also want the items to possibly move UP, LEFT/RIGHT into Position.

I added more to my original post up top that explains better.

Comment: @matt: So basically, the bottle moves with the scroll bar?

Comment: I had a bit of fun with your problem. http://jsfiddle.net/5A37m/ The only way I  saw it possible was to make a Scroller class for the image that would scroll. The present problem is with preloading images so that they don't take a lot of time to load. I tried to cache the images, but so far no luck. Maybe you can do some experimentation.

Comment: @RobinMaben bascially yes, but hopefully at a different pace then the actual page scrolls creating a parallax effect.

Comment: @matt: This case isn't really parallax. You have just one image floating over another. You need at least 3 points of reference for observing a parallax effect. Or, you can still give that illusion **if something were moving in the opposite direction of the scroll handle.**

Comment: @RobinMaben yes I know that I will have other effects scrolling as well ever so slightly, so really I guess what I am looking for is truly a parallax effect? See my post above I have added some links, one being a perfect example of what I am after.

Comment: @Rikonator lol nice! that is VERY close, the only thing, once you scroll past the effects if you scroll back up then down they do not animate again. is this generally the way parallax effects are done, with this method? I always thought the elements scrolled at a different pace then the scrollbar/page itself. SEE NEW EXAMPLES UP TOP. I added a perfect example of what I am after.

Comment: @matt: Hmm, I see what you mean. I have tried something based on your comments. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comment *`but hopefully at a different pace then the actual page scrolls creating a parallax effect.`* - I tried to simulate that effect.

Basically, the moving object travels at the **same rate** at which the page scrolls but covers a **different distance** proportional to the viewport (visible area)

[DEMO here.](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/GS9ed/2/)

**Note**: Use the scrollbar handle instead of the mouse wheel.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, its the use of parrallax that I guess tricks your eyes into items moving slower. The thing is I want them to kind of ease into place like the example I posted above (http://jessandruss.us/) I think were almost there...

Comment: @matt: It would be faster if you tried out some easing libraries than digging through already written code. Try [this](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/WebsiteScrolling/index_vertical.html) and [this](http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/).

Comment: that super scrollor is just what im after....thanks! ill leave this open for another day then reward.

Comment: @matt: There's [another badge](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/221/benefactor) for awarding the bounty *before the stipulated period ends*.. ;)  I missed out on mine, just thought I'd tell you. On a serious note though, I hope you're making progress with what you were trying.

Comment: missed it, oh well...next time. I will be starting this project next week and will keep you posted...you have skype btw?

Answer (score 7):

http://prinzhorn.github.com/skrollr/

This library is a native javascript (no need for jQuery etc.) parallax scrolling plugin. The plugin homepage has an actual demo of what you are looking for. Github repo is [here](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr).

Answer (score 1):

you should look at the source of  https://victoriabeckham.landrover.com/INT 
basically ther's a 'player' that handles some css properties that gives the parallax effect that you want to achieve; mainly is't matter of background-position 
alla the elements that should have such treatment are into a

Comment: Yes that is nice effect and quite close to what I want. Issue is there is so much code on that site its hard to find out just what I need. Like I said im looking for this exact effect:

http://jessandruss.us/ - this site does exactly what I want about 2/3 of the way down at this point (see screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/cdOA3.jpg)

Comment: here's ther's a library that should just fit frot your needs http://johnpolacek.github.com/superscrollorama/
keep in mind that also jessandruss.us has a bunch of code that doesn't serve your needs;  when i made such kind of sites i had to reverse engineer their source code and write a plugin nearly from scratch

Comment: that is pretty well exactly what I was hoping for when I created this post. Thanks! Ill leave this open for another day.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you would benefit from this book: [Supercharged Javascript Graphics](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449393632) it has plenty of tutorials and useful information. I personally learned a lot from it. here is a link to one of the examples from the book to wet your appetite [here.](http://www.professorcloud.com/supercharged/scrolling/tilescrolling.htm) and you can visit the authors website for more cool stuff [here.](http://www.professorcloud.com/mainsite/index.htm)

Comment: thanks but im trying to find an online tutorial, the simpler the better so I am hoping to find one that is more based on CSS if thats even possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Give jQuery [Transe](https://github.com/yckart/jQuery.transe.js) a chance.. There are some super simple **[demos](http://yckart.github.com/jQuery.transe.js/)** (no documentation yet) and it works even with [touch devices](http://yckart.github.com/jQuery.transe.js/examples/mobile/). *However, I've to say, that it is an early beta version, so be careful.*

BTW: It has only 8.682 kb